CPNowPlayingTemplate does not update CPNowPlayingShuffleButton state after changing shuffle mode
I am integrating CarPlay functionality in my existing iOS Music App. I have added Shuffle button in CPNowPlayingTemplate. CarPlay simulator is showing this button but it is not updating its state when I change the value of MPRemoteCommandCenter.shared().changeShuffleModeCommand.currentShuffleType its handler.
var defaultShuffleButton = CPNowPlayingShuffleButton { button in
        if MPRemoteCommandCenter.shared().changeShuffleModeCommand.currentShuffleType == MPShuffleType.off {
            MPRemoteCommandCenter.shared().changeShuffleModeCommand.currentShuffleType = MPShuffleType.collections
            button.isSelected = true
        } else if MPRemoteCommandCenter.shared().changeShuffleModeCommand.currentShuffleType == MPShuffleType.collections {
            MPRemoteCommandCenter.shared().changeShuffleModeCommand.currentShuffleType = MPShuffleType.items
            button.isSelected = true
        } else if MPRemoteCommandCenter.shared().changeShuffleModeCommand.currentShuffleType == MPShuffleType.items {
            MPRemoteCommandCenter.shared().changeShuffleModeCommand.currentShuffleType = MPShuffleType.off
            button.isSelected = false
        }
    }
    
    func templateApplicationScene(_ templateApplicationScene: CPTemplateApplicationScene, didConnect interfaceController: CPInterfaceController) {
        self.interfaceController = interfaceController
        MPRemoteCommandCenter.shared().changeShuffleModeCommand.isEnabled = true
        CPNowPlayingTemplate.shared.updateNowPlayingButtons([defaultShuffleButton])
    }

I have gone through the Apple documentation but could not find anything regarding this issue. It says in your handler, change the shuffle mode to the new value I can see in the logs that value of MPRemoteCommandCenter is being changed but CPNowPlayingTemplate is not updating the button states.
Thanks in advance!
